# PHP/HTML : Display result on the same web page

Tags: php, html

I have 2 php files. One of which has a form with a submit button. On clicking that, I am redirected to another page that displays "Hello World". I want that the result should be displayed on the same page rather than being redirected.I have tried the hacks given on the internet but nothing seems to work.

First file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$query=$_GET['query'];
echo $query;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="GET" action="/display.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: by same page do you mean same url ?

Comment: modify action arrtibute of the form to request page.

Comment: @niceman Yes on the same URL

Comment: <?php
<form  method="GET" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$query=$_GET['query'];
echo $query;  echo "Hello World";
}
?>

Comment: If that is an answer, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['query']) && !empty($_GET['query'])){
    $query = trim( $_GET['query'] );
    echo $query;
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="GET" action="./display.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
  header("location:index.php?query=Hello World");
?>
```

**NOTE** Keep both files are in same folder.

Comment: can't the OP just change action to `index.php` and get rid of `display.php` altogether ?

Comment: Doesn't display anything :(

Comment: I forgot to add dot before the backshlash, so now added. Its working and tested.

Comment: @niceman, dude may be he validating something on next page, so I just make the things working else your suggestion is also good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add click event to the button. Attach an ajax call on click event so that it will display hello world without redirection

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP wants

Comment: Need to display helloworld on the same page without redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why have 2 files when you can do it in one.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $query=$_GET['submit'];
    echo $query;    //print "Hello World"
  }       
?>
<html>

  <body>
       <form  method="GET" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Hello World" />
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the action attribute empty, and the form will submit to the current page.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

---

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to display a variable sent from the form.

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : ''; ?>
```

---

**Sample Code:**

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>
        foo = <?php echo isset($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : ''; ?>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
        echo 'Hello World';
    } 
?>

<html>
    <body>
         <form  method="GET" action="./display.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
         </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about include display.php
If you simply want the submit button to display "Hello World " on the same page replace action="/display.php" WITH action="" so the submit button posts to the page itself, when you click submit 
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) will return bool 1 and will execute the code to include display.php, which outputs 
"Hello World". You could easily also just echo "Hello world" instead of include 'display.php'

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
include 'display.php';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="GET" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: try to explain something about how will this solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

What about just using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  include('second.php');
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will do

Comment: May you explain the reason?

Comment: without changing form's `action` attribute, the include won't be reached

Comment: Of course you have to use `include` on the file reached by form submit..